# How do I copy files that I just searched for via the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Using Ubuntu 12.04 I need help on copying files that were returned from a search with `grep` .

I have many pdf files, so to filter specific named files I am using General grep command as 
 follows.

```
raja@badfox:~/Desktop/mtech/M.Tech II Sem-April 2012$ grep "DESIGN OF FAULT TOLERANT SYSTEMS" *.pdf
Binary file NR-DESIGN OF FAULT TOLERANT SYSTEMS.pdf matches
Binary file R09-DESIGN OF FAULT TOLERANT SYSTEMS.pdf matches
```

How do I automatically copy the files returned from the search to another directory?

Comment: Do you want to copy files based on the **name of the file**? (Then just [do it this way](http://askubuntu.com/a/171261/22949).) Or do you want to copy all files that *contain* a certain string? Also, remember that if a string appears in a PDF when you view it, that string will often *but not always* appear as a contiguous sequence of characters in the PDF file itself, as there may be formatting in the string that breaks it up.

Comment: @Ankit as i mentioned only a specific files , not all .

Comment: based on their name @EliahKagan ,:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier way to do it would be to just use `cp`.

```
cp *"DESIGN OF FAULT TOLERANT SYSTEMS"*.pdf /some/folder/
```

Comment: this is great and simple .

Comment: Thanks. As tgm4883 answered, you can use `grep`, but it is a lot harder to remember the commands to do so if you aren't using the advanced features of `grep`.

Comment: Also, `grep` (as used in the question) looks *in* the files, not at their names. A file won't always contain its own name.

Comment: I've deleted my other answer as this one is the best for what the user wants to do, and it's far more work to even correct mine to give the user what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this in general when you are searching for files is in conjunction with the `find` command, e.g.

```
find -name "*DESIGN OF FAULT TOLERANT SYSTEMS*.pdf" -exec cp '{}' /some/folder/ \;
```

which combines the searching and copying (generally any action you want to perform on the files) into one command.

If you wanted to limit the search to the current directory you could add the `-maxdepth 1` option to the find command.

`find` has many options for specifying which paths to search or not search, including checking modification times, path specifiers, filenames, and many more. Used correctly it's an extremely powerful tool.

Comment: Note - this will copy files found in the current directory and any subdirectory. So, for example if you have archived versions of the DESIGN* PDF files in a subdir, those would be found and copied to the target location.

Comment: @CodeFriendly - Cheers, updated the post